# How to find the window reference where a NSButton is located from its IBAction call? (Cocoa Objective-C)

Tags: cocoa

How can I find the window reference where the NSButton is located from its IBAction call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)someAction:(NSButton *)sender;
{
    NSWindow *theWindow = [sender window];
}
```

Comment: Method! They're called **methods**!

Comment: I thought that the 2 terms can be used interchangeably.  Thanks for pointing it out.  The question is definitely answered perfectly.  But I cannot find the check box to mark the question as answered.  Sounds silly.  This is my very first question on "stackoverflow" you may have to show me how to mark it as answered ... Thanks + Happy New Year.

Comment: Functions are things like `NSMakeRect()`; Note how they're not called *on* a particular object. There should be a big checkmark/tick to the left of my answer you can select.

Comment: Thanks for giving an example of NS functions.  Glad to hear that traditional functions are still being implemented.  I thought that they would associate every code routine to a class or object.  Also have you ever tried to customize the display color of the debugging console in xCode ?  Info from various sites say it can be done in menu : xCode - Preferences - Debugging and click on "SetFont".  I can find the "SetFont" button but its font and font background color options doesn't seem to work.  (xCode Version 3.2.4  IDE 1708.0)